# Conditional in Ruby Array.collect Iterator Block

Tags: arrays, ruby, iterator, block, collect

Can anybody shine some light on why this is behaving like this?  I'm expecting the collection to omit nil results, and only collect those that qualify under the condition of the `include?`.  First and third result entries, I expect to not be there.  For some reason, they are indeed included.  What am I doing wrong?

```
f = [
{"title"=>"Tuesday: Cloudy. High plus 12.",
"link"=>{"type"=>"text/html",
  "href"=>"https://www.weather.gc.ca/city/pages/mb-42_metric_e.html"}},

{"title"=>"Tuesday night: Cloudy. High plus 2.",
"link"=>{"type"=>"text/html",
  "href"=>"https://www.weather.gc.ca/city/pages/mb-42_metric_e.html"}},

{"title"=>"Wednesday: Cloudy. High plus 10.",
"link"=>{"type"=>"text/html",
  "href"=>"https://www.weather.gc.ca/city/pages/mb-42_metric_e.html"}},

{"title"=>"Tuesday night: Cloudy. High plus 2.",
"link"=>{"type"=>"text/html",
  "href"=>"https://www.weather.gc.ca/city/pages/mb-42_metric_e.html"}}
]

conditions = f.collect { |i| i['title'] if i['title'].include?('night') }
==> [nil, "Tuesday night: Cloudy. High plus 2.", nil, "Tuesday night: Cloudy. High plus 2."]
```

Answer (score 3):

This is expected behaviour - `map` transforms an array one to one and any statement in form:

```
do_sth if some_condition
```

returns `nil` when some condition is falsey and `nil` is just an object as anything else.

Standard way of dealing with this would be either to use `select` before call to map or to call `compact` after `map`.

Since ruby 2.7 we have another method combining the two: [filter_map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-filter_map) which ignores returned falsy values:

```
conditions = f.filter_map { |i| i['title'] if i['title'].include?('night') }
==> ["Tuesday night: Cloudy. High plus 2.", "Tuesday night: Cloudy. High plus 2."]
```

Comment: Probably why they added that method, as people were applying conditions and getting `nils`.

Answer (score 1):

Because in every Iteration, collect/map returns something (also nil in this case)...

You could use select to filter your array. Something like this:

```
f.select { |i| i['title'].include?('night') }.collect {|i| i['title']}
```

Comment: Ya I was expecting nils to not show up.  I guess it demonstrates an iteration.  I now have chosen `Array.compact` to rid the `nil` entries.

Answer (score 0):

`#map` transforms one collection to another collection of the same size. If the block returns `nil` values, then those `nil`s will end up in the new collection.

A statement like `i['title'] if i['title'].include?('night')` will return `nil` in the case that the title does not contain *night*.

You can either use `#filter_map`, `#select` + `#map`, `#inject` or `#each_with_object`

I ran a quick micro-benchmark and suprisingly iterating the collection twice (using `#select` AND `#map`) is not slower.

```rb
items = [
{"title"=>"Tuesday: Cloudy. High plus 12.",
"link"=>{"type"=>"text/html",
  "href"=>"https://www.weather.gc.ca/city/pages/mb-42_metric_e.html"}},

{"title"=>"Tuesday night: Cloudy. High plus 2.",
"link"=>{"type"=>"text/html",
  "href"=>"https://www.weather.gc.ca/city/pages/mb-42_metric_e.html"}},

{"title"=>"Wednesday: Cloudy. High plus 10.",
"link"=>{"type"=>"text/html",
  "href"=>"https://www.weather.gc.ca/city/pages/mb-42_metric_e.html"}},

{"title"=>"Tuesday night: Cloudy. High plus 2.",
"link"=>{"type"=>"text/html",
  "href"=>"https://www.weather.gc.ca/city/pages/mb-42_metric_e.html"}}
]
require "benchmark/ips"
Benchmark.ips do |x|
  x.compare!
  x.report("filter_map") do
    items.filter_map { |item| item["title"] if item["title"].include?("night")}
  end
  x.report("select_map") do
    items.select { |item| item["title"].include?("night") }.map { |item| item["title"] }
  end
  x.report("each_with_object") do
    items.each_with_object([]) { |item, accu| accu << item["title"] if item["title"].include?("night"); nil }
  end
  x.report("inject") do
    items.inject([]) { |accu, item| accu << item["title"] if item["title"].include?("night"); accu }
  end
end
```